# AWS API unable to validate query string (specifically - "VpcId=vpc-1738886c")

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, amazon-web-services

I am trying to send a API query for Subnet Creation. Please note that the authentication code is working the problem is just with the parameter string:

```
request_parameters = 'Action=CreateSubnet&**VpcId=vpc-1738886c**&CidrBlock=20.20.3.0%2F28&Version=2016-11-15'
```

When I send this, I get: **AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials**

For the exact same code, when I send:

```
"request_parameters = 'Action=CreateVpc&CidrBlock=20.20.3.0%2F24&Version=2016-11-15'"    #  It works!!
```

I am guessing there is something wrong with: ***VpcId=vpc-1738886c***

Being same user, I am able to create a subnet in that VPC with same CIDR block in the console so permission doesn't seem to be an issue.

Please can you advise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the whole call using `boto3` please

Comment: I am not using boto3 instead sending API request after version 4 signing (link with code can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html))

Answer (score 0):

*"AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials"* **should** mean you have an issue in the signing code -- not in the actual parameters.

Initially, it's hard to see why that might be the case, here... but it is.

The problem lies in the fact that you need to be signing the *canonical representation* of the query string... which means the parameters must be sorted lexically when signing:

```
# canonical representation
Action=CreateSubnet&CidrBlock=20.20.3.0%2F28&Version=2016-11-15&VpcId=vpc-1738886c
```

There can be no safe assumptions about the order in which a query string's parameters may change end-to-end on the Internet, so the AWS signing algorithms require them to be sorted for signing.  The order in the actual HTTP request doesn't matter, but the order when signing does.